# To what extent does a compiler change a dynamic binding to static?

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization

```
class base
{
public:
std::string name() { return basename; }
virtual void print(std::ostream &os) { os << basename; }
private:
std::string basename = "base\n";
};

class derived : public base
{
public:
void print(std::ostream &os) override { base::print(os); os << " derived\n " << i; }

private:
int i;
};

int main()
{
// ex15.14
base bobj;
base *bp1 = &bobj;
base &br1 = bobj;
derived dobj;
base *bp2 = &dobj;
base &br2 = dobj;

// a.  this is an object, so compile time.
//bobj.print(std::cout);

// b.  this is an object, so compile time.
//dobj.print(std::cout);

// c.  function name is not virtual , so no dynamic
//     binding happens.so compile time
//std::cout << bp1->name();

// d.  function name is not virtual , so no dynamic
//     binding happens.so compile time
//std::cout << bp2->name();

// e.  run time
//br1.print(std::cout);

// f.  run time
//br2.print(std::cout);


return 0;
}
```

Notice e and f, br1 and br2 are references to base class object bobj and derived class object dobj. Can a good c++ compiler detect and optimize the code for this so there's no dynamic binding process at all?

Comment: Yes, they [sometimes](https://godbolt.org/g/8ksE9t) do. :-)

Comment: Yes, certainly. The compiler can know the dynamic type at compile-time, and emit a call to the derived class' member, even though the code uses a reference to the base class type.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. If the compiler can statically prove that a virtual method call always targets objects of the same type (and sometimes it can), it is allowed to optimize the call to not use the dispatch vector but instead statically bind to the actual implementation.

This analysis is usually a simple, context-insensitive, flow-insensitive variant of pointer analysis which can be run efficiently by the compiler. It will naturally not detect all possible optimization points, but chances are good that it will hit the obvious ones.

This is an important technique for efficiently compiling languages that always use dynamic dispatch, like Java.